# Lua | String Pattern exclusion

Tags: lua

So for I game I want the user to be able to do commands.
For simplicity all parameters are put into a table.

```
Example: "message all Hello" -> {"message","all","Hello"}
```

For that I've used the alphanumeric pattern (%w).
Problem is that characters like: _ ; : . Simply can not be used, since they're not alphanumeric.
Is there anyway to use the all characters pattern(.), but ignore spaces.
Or is there any better way to do it?
Thank you for your help

Comment: How about the "everything but spaces pattern" `[^ ]`?

Comment: This has been the pattern i've been looking for! thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to Lua docs:

> Making the letter after the % uppercase inverts the class, so %D will match all non-digit characters.

So the pattern you're looking for is `%S+`.

Comment: Ah i missed that. Thank you!